# Unable to install composer packages

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

```
Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires realdriss/platform ^1.0 -> satisfiable by realdriss/platform[v1.0.0].
- realdriss/platform v1.0.0 requires kris/laravel-form-builder 1.16.x-dev -> found kris/laravel-form-builder[dev-master, 0.1.8, 1.0, ..., 1.52.x-dev (alias of dev-master), 2.x-dev] but it does not match the constraint.
Problem 2
- realdriss/platform v1.0.0 requires kris/laravel-form-builder 1.16.x-dev -> found kris/laravel-form-builder[dev-master, 0.1.8, 1.0, ..., 1.52.x-dev (alias of dev-master), 2.x-dev] but it does not match the constraint.
- realdriss/shortcode v1.0.0 requires realdriss/platform *@dev -> satisfiable by realdriss/platform[v1.0.0].
- Root composer.json requires realdriss/shortcode ^1.0 -> satisfiable by realdriss/shortcode[v1.0.0].
```

Command:
`composer install --prefer-source`

These are the contents of my composer.json

```
{
  "name": "laravel/laravel",
  "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
  "keywords": [
    "framework",
    "laravel"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "type": "project",
  "require": {
    "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
    "ext-curl": "*",
    "ext-json": "*",
    "ext-zip": "*",
    "beyondcode/laravel-websockets": "^1.14",
    "realdriss/menu": "^1.0",
    "realdriss/page": "^1.0",
    "realdriss/platform": "^1.0",
    "realdriss/plugin-management": "^1.0",
    "realdriss/shortcode": "^1.0",
    "realdriss/theme": "^1.0",
    "doctrine/dbal": "^3.0",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
    "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
    "gathuku/laravelmpesa": "^1.2",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
    "laravel/framework": "^8.12",
    "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^1.0",
    "pusher/pusher-php-server": "~3.0",
    "realdriss/sitemap": "*",
    "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": "^2.0"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.2",
    "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^2.6",
    "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.9",
    "facade/ignition": "^2.5",
    "fakerphp/faker": "^1.10",
    "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.2",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.2",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.3.3"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "app/",
      "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
      "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
    }
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
  },
  "extra": {
    "laravel": {
      "dont-discover": []
    },
    "merge-plugin": {
      "include": [],
      "recurse": false,
      "replace": false,
      "ignore-duplicates": false,
      "merge-dev": false,
      "merge-extra": false,
      "merge-extra-deep": false,
      "merge-scripts": false
    },
    "google/apiclient-services": [
      "Analytics"
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
      "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
      "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
    ],
    "post-autoload-dump": [
      "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
      "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
      "Google\\Task\\Composer::cleanup"
    ]
  },
  "config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true,
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "allow-plugins": {
      "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": true
    }
  },
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
  "prefer-stable": true,
  "repositories": []
}
```

Comment: where is realdriss/platform[v1.0.0] referenced here?

Comment: I tried your composer.json file and it worked flawlessly for me. You could try deleting the entire vendor directory and/or the composer cache with lock file if they are already installed.

Comment: You could also try changing `minimum-stability` to `stable`  because for some reason it seems to be selecting dev packages which it really shouldn't given your dependencies

Comment: "realdriss/platform v1.0.0 requires kris/laravel-form-builder 1.16.x-dev" - that sounds strange. packagist.org does not list that exact requirement

Answer (score 1):

A fast solution you could make

### #1

Remove this package `realdriss/platform` from your composer file manually

### #2

install it again and it will find the best version for your case using this command

```
composer require realdriss/platform
```